# Why is there an extra line after my input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a python program where right triangles of varying sizes can be made. The first input takes in the number of triangles, and the second input takes in 2 integers separated by spaces, the first of which determines the size, and the second determines its orientation.

That part of the code is going along well, but there's this one thing that's bugging me. After the inputting the 2nd line, there appears an extra blank line break that doesn't appear to be created by any of the print statements in my code. Why is it like that?

Code below.

```
def triangle (size, orient):
    if (orient==1):
        for x in range (size, 0, -1):
            for y in range (x):
                print('#', end='')
            print('')
    elif (orient==2):
        for x in range (size,0,-1):
            for y in range (size-x):
                print (' ', end='')
            for y in range (x):
                print('#', end='')
            print('')
    elif(orient==3):
        for x in range (size+1):
            for y in range (x):
                print('#', end='')
            print('')
    elif(orient==4):
        for x in range (size):
            for y in range (size-x-1):
                print (' ', end='')
            for y in range (x+1):
                print ('#', end='')
            print ('')
num1 = int(input())
sizes = []
orients = []
for x in range(num1):
    input = input()
    array = input.split(' ')
    sizes.append(int(array[0]))
    orients.append(int(array[1]))
for x in range (num1):
    triangle(sizes[x],orients[x])
    print('')
```

Comment: Please show a complete run of the program with input and output as properly formatted text in the question. By the way: Don't use names of standard library functions (like "input") as variable names.

Comment: I see a bunch of `print('')`'s what are they for?

Comment: `input = input()` it is usually a bad idea to use a keyword/built-in as a name - it can make hard to interpret bugs. ... Unless you do it with intent and foreknowledge.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many comments indicate problems you likely want to fix, but the root of your problem is in your `orient==3` code. In Python, the default range starts at 0. For the first iteration through, you're printing zero hash marks. When you add 1 to the size at the end, you also need to add 1 at the start. Change the loop to `for x in range(1, size)`, and you'll get what you expect.